# How much does a contract-for-hire employee owe to their contractor?

Tags: contracts

I am a contractor employee  in a contract for hire position. Its been about 1.5 months and its becoming clear this job was not what the interviewer nor my boss( from the contracting company) described. One described it as web work, the other as application work, but I'm pretty much wrestling with excel all day and am doing very little coding. Plus the coding department is VERY small (3 people including me) and I'm basically at the ceiling with people who have been working here for years. I was hesistant to do contract work because it's short term, but my boss described it as a chance to get into new opportunities quickly. However, when I mentioned moving in year, my boss quickly said I couldn't do that to the person who had me in a contract to hire position. The job is fine the people are fine and the pay is very good but I don't want to out a year in here for politeness, just to start over again and wait another year before I move up. What should I do? Am I obligated to get hired in the contract for hire?

Comment: Typed on my phone during a mandated break! Excuse typos

Comment: What country.  Based on your comment "Mandated break" i am suspecting outside the US but I do not know

Answer (score 2):

> What should I do? Am I obligated to get hired in the contract for hire?

Like smooth_smoothie said, different countries (and even different states!) will have different laws about contractors and the obligations.  In general, the terms of your contract govern how/when you can leave.  There is often a termination provision that will specify how you can/should leave.  Most contracts only require you to give notice (like 30 days notice), and it is very rare for a contract to require you to accept an offer for employment.  But be forewarned, most contractors are expected not to do substantial work during that notice period.

That said, how you depart and how you leave the company that has contracted you will make a **huge difference** in how you are perceived.  As a consultant/contractor, your reputation is extremely important.  So, when you are leaving, I would recommend that you be 100% professional and make sure that any outstanding projects are finished.  Future clients will call previous clients for references, and you always want to make sure that your previous clients were happy and satisfied with your work product.

Answer (score 0):

You can literally leave at will (You can also be fired at will), that is literally one of the aspect of Contract work that makes it different from let's say a full time job (among other things like benefits). You don't have any obligations to your   company, however the look and feel of leaving a job after 1 month on your resume might be something you will have to be ready to explain to future employers.

Edit: I'm assuming you are in Canada, since at-will employment in U.S. is a thing.

Comment: No, I will stay for my contract. I mean that they hired me temporarily expecting to hire me permanently but right now I do not think that will be so. I am less worried about them than my contracting company's opinion since they may lose the satisfaction of a customer and they have to find me a good job

Comment: Yes they will loose out on revenue. But if you explain your decision they SHOULD understand because they failed you to a certain extent as well.